# How to inject code into a running process using C/C++

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, gdb, code-injection

I am looking for advice on how to manipulate functions by injecting code directly into memory during runtime.  The aim is to eventually run run an external application that is able to manipulate running processes for optimisation purposes.  So far, I have gone down the route of using GDB to manipulate memory, by following this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33340/Code-Injection-into-Running-Linux-Application?fid=1534990&df=90&mpp=10&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4678205

However, it is fairly dated now and i cant seem to get it working on a 64-bit architecture... I would appreciate any advice on this topic.  Cheers

Comment: You can write to the memory of the other process using ptrace directly. It's the same syscall gdb uses. http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace . As for getting code in which will actually do anything usefull, relocate against symbols etc., that sounds like a major undertaking.

Answer (score -4):

To allow this opens up *huge* security vulnerabilities, so it is strictly forbidden in any sane environment. Newer Linux in particular (and more so on x86_64) strictly separates executable memory areas from modifiable areas. Besides, modern CPUs don't react kindly to code changes outside their caches and such. Perhaps the nearest would be to load shared libraries dynamically.

This kind of operation is part of the workings of most scripting languages, like Perl or Python.

Comment: What about GDB's alter execution functionally? where your able to patch a running application on the fly. @Magnus Reftel [link](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gdb/gdb_12.html)

Comment: @StuartGordon, that it *can* be done (in a debugger, of all things) doesn't mean it is a good idea in *production* code of any sort.